# Can absolute convergent series be expressed as sum of two series?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C\subset \omega \bigwedge A\bigcap B = \emptyset \bigwedge A\bigcup B = C$.

Let $\{x_i\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative reals.

Suppose $C$ is infinite and $\sum_{i\in C} x_i$ converges. (Since it converges absolutely, it makes sense to define its sum in this way)

Then $\sum_{i\in C} x_i = \sum_{i\in B} x_i + \sum_{i\in A} x_i$, when $A,B$ are infinite?

Comment: What's $\omega$?

Comment: @Gerry It was a typo. Edited.

Comment: What's $\omega$?

Comment: $\omega=\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$

Comment: I guess $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers and the definition of $\sum_{x\in S}x$ is $\sup_{J\in\mathcal P_f(S)}\sum_{j\in J}x_j$, where $\{x_j\}$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers, and $\mathcal P_f(S)$ is the collection of finite subsets of $S$.

Comment: @Kevin $\omega$ is an inductive set which has the same property of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If a series of real numbers is absolutely convergent, then
$S=\sum_{i\in C}x_i$ means this: For each $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite set $F\subseteq C$ such that for each finite set $G\supseteq F$ you have $|S-\sum_{i\in G} x_i| < \varepsilon$. Using this definition you should be able to show that what you wrote is true. Similar argument should work in more general setting - for [unconditionally convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional_convergence) series.

Comment: @David I meant $\sum_{i\in C} x_i$ to be the series of any arrangement of $\{x_i\}_{i\in C}$. (I don't know if it is equivalent to your definition, but it seems it is.. Is it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Only after posting the answer below I've noticed the question is only about non-negative series. I'll leave the answer here, since I think it might be useful anyway. (It is about a slightly more general question.)

---

We can even dispose the countability condition - we can have arbitrary index set.

Standard definition of *absolute convergence* of $\sum_{i\in I} x_i$, where each $x_i$ are real numbers, is that:

> $S$ is the sum of this series if and only if for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a finite subset $F\subseteq I$ such that for each finite set $G\supset F$, $G\subseteq C$, we have $\left|\sum_{i\in G}x_i-S\right|<\varepsilon$.

This is the same definition as the one given in answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70194/does-uncountable-summation-with-a-finite-sum-ever-occur-in-mathematics), but I rewrote it in a way which avoids mentioning nets.

You can check that if $I=\mathbb N$ this is the same as saying that $\sum x_i$ converges absolutely to $S$. (For details see below.)

In fact we could use the same definition with $x_i\in X$ where $X$ is arbitrary linear normed space. It can be shown that if $X$ is a Banach space, then for sequences this is equivalent to [uncoditional convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional_convergence), see e.g. Heil, A basis theory primer, [p.93-94](http://books.google.com/books?id=prfuUT0Sw-AC&pg=PA93) or Theorem 14.9 in Pete L. Clark's [Honors Calculus notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf). It is not true that this is the same as [absolute convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Rearrangements_and_unconditional_convergence), but in finitely dimensional Banach spaces this two notions coincide. Unconditional and absolute convergence are also discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143160/proving-that-unconditional-convergence-is-equivalent-to-absolute-convergence).

---

Now if we work with the above definition and if $C=A\cup B$, where $A$, $B$ are disjoint and if we have
$$S_1=\sum_{i\in A} x_i \qquad S_2=\sum_{i\in B} x_i$$
then for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite subset $F_1\subseteq A$ such that for every finite $G$ fulfilling $F_1\subseteq G\subseteq A$ we have
$$\left|\sum_{i\in G} x_i-S_1\right|<\varepsilon/2$$ and we also have $F_2$ such that for finite $G$ fulfilling $F_2\subseteq G\subseteq B$ we have
$$\left|\sum_{i\in G} x_i-S_2\right|<\varepsilon/2.$$

Together we get (using triangle inequality) that for each finite set $G\subseteq C$ such that $G\supseteq F_1\cup F_2$
$$\left|\sum_{i\in G} x_i - (S_1+S_2)\right|<\varepsilon.$$

So we have shown that if $\sum_{i\in A} x_i=S_1$ exists and $\sum_{i\in B}=S_2$ exists, then $\sum_{i\in C}=S$ exists and it is equal to the sum $S=S_1+S_2$.

---

To see that if $\sum_{i\in C} x_i$ exists (in the sense of the above definition) then the sum $\sum_{i\in A} x_i$ exists we may use Cauchy criterion.
The following is the formulation from [Dixmier's General Topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=eKzXj64JeZoC):

> **9.1.6. Theorem** (Cauchy's Criterion). Let $E$ be a Banach space, $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of elements of $E$.
> The following conditions are equivalent:
> (i) the family $(x_i)_{i\in l}$ is summable;
> (ii) for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a finite subset $J_0$ of $I$ such that, for every
> finite subset $K$ of $I$ disjoint from $J_0$, one has $\|\sum_{i\in K} x_i\|  < \varepsilon$.

(By summable family the author means that $\sum_{i\in I} x_i$ exists in the sense of the above definition.)

Again, for the case of real numbers you can find this result in [Pete L. Clark's notes Honors Calculus](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400full.pdf) as
Theorem 14.5 (Cauchy Criteria for Unordered Summation). (Including the proof.)

It is relatively easy to see that if $A\subseteq C$ and $\sum_{i\in C} x_i$ fulfills Cauchy condition, then so does $\sum_{i\in A} x_i$.

---

Now back to the case $I=\mathbb N$.

Suppose that a series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$ is absolutely convergent to $S$. Then we also have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|<\infty$. This implies that, for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $n_0$ such that $$\left|\sum_{i=n_0+1}^{n_0+k} x_i\right|\le\sum_{i=n_0+1}^{n_0+k} |x_i|<\varepsilon/2$$ holds for each $k$. We can choose $n_0$ such that, in addition to the above condition, $\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n_0}-S\right|<\varepsilon/2$.
So we can choose $F=\{1,2,\dots,n_0\}$ and we get that for any $\{1,2,\dots,n_0\}\subseteq G\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n_0+k\}$ we also have
$$\left|\sum_{i\in G\setminus F} x_i\right| \le \sum_{i\in G\setminus F} |x_i| \le \sum_{i=n_0+1}^{n_0+k} |x_i| < \varepsilon/2$$
which together with
$$\left|\sum_{i\in F} x_i-S\right| < \varepsilon/2$$
implies
$$\left|\sum_{i\in G} x_i-S\right| < \varepsilon.$$

On the other hand, if $\sum_{i\in\mathbb N} x_i$ fulfills the above condition then each reordering $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_{\pi(i)}$ is convergent. (For any given $\varepsilon>0$ we choose $n_0$ large enough so that $\{x_{\pi(1)},\dots,x_{\pi(n_0)}\}\supseteq F$.) This implies that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$
is absolutely convergent.

Comment: This is really useful to me. Thank you. I didn't even know that there is a definition for $\sum_{i\in I} x_i$, but i just used it since any rearrangement of $\sum x_i$ has the same sum if $I$ is countable.

Comment: Does the first definition not hold for $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: @Martine I mean.. If $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$, the definition you wrote and 'general definition' are not equivalent?

Comment: @Katlus Certainly you can use the above definition in $\mathbb R^k$. It will be the same thing as convergence in each coordinate. If you use the norm $\|(x_1,\dots,x_k)\|=|x_1|+\dots+|x_k|$ on $\mathbb R^k$, then you see that absolute convergence is the same as absolute convergence in each coordinate. (It is good to keep in mind that all norm on a $\mathbb R^k$ are equivalent.) BTW I've added some pointers to my post.

Comment: In the proof showing '$\sum_{i\in C} x_i = \sum_{i\in A} x_i + \sum_{i\in B} x_i$, i understand that existence of $S_1,S_2$ is guranteed when $C$ is countable, but if $C$ is arbitrary how come their existences are guranteed?

Comment: Never mind.. you answered exactly what i asked and now i'm asking a different question...

Comment: @Katlus I have only shown one direction, but the other one can be shown using Cauchy criterion. (I have added it to the post.)

Answer (score 3):

The sum of a countable family of non-negative numbers is the supremum of the set of sums of finite subfamilies. This definition does not use any order on the (index set of) the family. Since a finite subset of $C$ splits into a finite subset of $A$ and a finite subset of $B$, and conversely any two such finite subsets unite to a finite subset of $C$, you can easily prove $\sum_{i\in C} x_i = \sum_{i\in B} x_i + \sum_{i\in A} x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Your theorem is true if the sum converges absolutely.

If not, $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is a counterexample. Observe that $$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$$
converges (since $x_n$ has alternating signs, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} x_n = 0$), but both of the sums $$
\begin{eqnarray}
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{2n} &\text{ and }&
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{2n+1} 
\end{eqnarray}
$$
diverge.

Note, btw, that the notation $\sum_{i\in C} x_i$ already implies that the sum is invariant under at least some reorderings, since it doesn't specify any *particular* ordering. How trivial or non-trivial the proof of your theorem is depends on the *precise* definition you use for $\sum_{i\in C} x_i$.

Comment: It is absolutely convergent..I said $\{x_i\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative reals.

Comment: @Katlus Oh, sorry, I missed that. It works then, because you may reorder absolutely convergent series arbitrarily.

Comment: Yes, i think it works, but i don't know how to prove the equality holds. Would you help me how to show this?