# Are absolutely convergent sums exactly those which can be reordered?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, permutations, absolute-convergence

If an infinite sum is absolutely convergent, its limit remains the same however the terms are permuted. Does a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ exist such that $\sum_n a_{\small P(n)}$ is the same for all permutations $P:\mathbb{N}\overset{\text{bijectively}}{\to}\mathbb{N}$, and such that $\sum_n |a_n|$ diverge?

Comment: No. It has been asked before. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143160/proving-that-unconditional-convergence-is-equivalent-to-absolute-convergence).

Comment: No, if all the permuted series converge then the original series converges absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that when you write “is the same” what you mean is “is the same real number”, then the answer is negative, by the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).