# Question about the definition of signed measure

Tags: measure-theory

In my book for a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$, a *signed measure* on it is a function $\mu: \mathcal{A}\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$ such that

$(1)$ $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$;
$(2)$ If $A_1,\cdots, A_k, \cdots$ are pairwise disjoint sets, then we have
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu(A_i),
$$
and if $\mu(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i)$ is finite then the right side must absolutely converge to a number.

My question is, if $\mu(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i) = \infty$, how can we check whether the right side is infinity? I took real analysis a while ago and forgot a lot about series. Is it possible that $\sum_i^\infty a_i = \infty$ but after reordering it terms, it sums to a number or is even divergent (no value)?

Thanks!

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = +\infty$ we can assume without loss of generality that $a_i\geqslant 0$ for all $i$ since $\infty-x=\infty$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\infty-\infty$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is certainly possible to have $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i=\infty$, and yet a reordering of the terms gives a convergent series - consider the alternating harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, which converges, but can be reordered to diverge to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$ (or to oscillate between any number of values).

However, this definition asserts that that does not happen in the case of a signed measure, since reordering the terms does not change the left hand side of

$$\mu(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu(A_i).$$

In fact, the statement that the sum on the right must converge absolutely to a number did not have to be included in the definition, since it is an immediate consequence of the fact that the value of sum is independent of ordering (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143160/1210477) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)).

Note also that since $\mu$ does not ever take a value of $-\infty$, the sum of all the negative terms on the right hand side must be finite.